# GUIボタンが押せないのですが

Tags: unity3d

MobileSingleStickControlを使って仮想ボタンでのジャンプボタンを作ったのですが、ボタンが押されたことを一回目だけ取るのですが二回目以降ボタンが全く反応しなくなってしまいます。
`Debug.Log ("update");`はコンソールで呼ばれ続けているのに、
`Debug.Log ("Input.getButtonDown jump");`　１回
`Debug.Log("jump true");`　１回
`Debug.Log ("jump false");`　１１回
のように表示され、ボタンが押されたということを二度と受け取らなくなってしまいます。
どのようにすれば　ボタンとして動かすことが出来るのでしょうか

[ButtonHandler.cs]

```
using System;
using UnityEngine;

namespace UnityStandardAssets.CrossPlatformInput
{
    public class ButtonHandler : MonoBehaviour
    {

        public string Name;

        void OnEnable()
        {

        }

        public void SetDownState()
        {
            CrossPlatformInputManager.SetButtonDown(Name);
        }


        public void SetUpState()
        {
            CrossPlatformInputManager.SetButtonUp(Name);
        }


        public void SetAxisPositiveState()
        {
            CrossPlatformInputManager.SetAxisPositive(Name);
        }


        public void SetAxisNeutralState()
        {
            CrossPlatformInputManager.SetAxisZero(Name);
        }


        public void SetAxisNegativeState()
        {
            CrossPlatformInputManager.SetAxisNegative(Name);
        }

        public void Update()
        {
            Debug.Log ("update");
            if (UnityStandardAssets.CrossPlatformInput.CrossPlatformInputManager.GetButtonDown("Jump"))
            {
                Debug.Log ("Input.getButtonDown jump");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[Jump.js]

```
#pragma strict

function Start () {

}

function Update () {
    var myAnimator=GetComponent(Animator);
    if (UnityStandardAssets.CrossPlatformInput.CrossPlatformInputManager.GetButtonDown("Jump"))
    {
        myAnimator.SetBool("Jump",true);
        Debug.Log("jump true");
    }


    var state:AnimatorStateInfo=myAnimator.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0);
    if(state.IsName("Locomotion.Jump"))
    {
        myAnimator.SetBool("Jump",false);
        Debug.Log ("jump false");
    }
}
```

[image: コンソール画面]

[image: Hierarchy]

[image: unity-chan]

Comment: こちらで質問内容のコードを試したのですが、Debug.Log("jump true")はボタンを押す度にちゃんと呼ばれたため、2,3質問させてください。
1.MobileSingleStickControlはStandard AssetsのMobileSingleStickControlのプレハブをそのまま使っているのでしょうか。
2.BuildSettingのプラットフォームは何を選択してますでしょうか。
3.MoblileInputの状態はEnable,Disableどちらになっていますか。仮想ボタンは実際には画面上にボタンは表示されているのでしょうか。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。

１．Standard Assets>CrossPlatformInput>Prefabs>MobileSingleStickControlをそのまま使っています。
２．BuildSettingはiOSです。
３．MoblileInputはEnableになっており、画面上にも表示されています。

Comment: うーん、やっぱり問題なくボタンは動いていますね。また2,3質問させてください。
1.Hierarchy上にはMobileSingleStickControl以外にはどんなGameObjectがありますか。
2.Jump.jsはどのGameObjectについていますか。
私のテスト環境では、MobileSingleStickControlとJump.jsを付けたGameObjectのみの環境です。

Comment: お時間を頂いてしまって恐縮です。
１．MobileSingleStickControl以外のGameObjectはジャンプさせたいキャラクター本体や、Cube等２２個ほどあります。
２．jump.jsはプレイヤーキャラクター本体に付いています。

プレイヤーキャラクターがunity-chanなのですが、このあたりが原因だったりするのでしょうか....

Comment: 一度MobileSingleStickControlとJump.jsだけを使ったシーンでテストしてもらったほうがいいかもしれませんね。
上記とは別件ですが、MobileSingleStickControlをHierarchy上に置いてシーンを実行するとEventSystemが自動で生成されると思いますが、そのEventSystemはボタンを押した際に変化などはありますか。

Comment: 新たにプロジェクトを作りunity-chanとMobileSingleStickControlとJump.jsのみで生成してみましたがやはり一度しかボタンを認識しませんでした。
EventSystemは特に変化を感じられませんでした。

Hierarchy等の構成をUPします。宜しくお願い致します。

Comment: GetButtonDown()の部分をGetButtonUp()やGetButton(に)変更しても反応しないでしょうか？

Comment: GetButtonUp()の時はButtonHandler.csのDebug.Log ("Input.getButtonDown jump");が表示されるのみでjump.jsのDebug.Log("jump true");は呼ばれていませんでした。

GetButton()の場合はjump.jsのmyAnimator.SetBool("Jump",true);が呼ばれ続け移動中はジャンプし続ける形になっています。

Comment: 移動制御中にジャンプし続けるということは、移動とジャンプは同じボタンで制御されていますか。
それともマルチタッチ中に件の不具合が発生していますか。

Comment: ジャンプボタンと移動キーは別になっています。また、ジャンプは移動中にしか出来ない設定になっています。
ゲーム開始→移動キーで移動は問題なく行われるのですが一度ジャンプボタンを押すと移動キーを動かした時に、移動→ジャンプ→着地→移動→ジャンプ→着地とジャンプキーを押していないのに移動中にジャンプをし続けてしまう状態です。